# How to make python request (oauth2)

Tags: python

i need to get the token for making the finale api rest requests.
The specs of the api are:

1. `basicAuthentication`    Use: the `client_id` and `client_secret` (both URL-encoded, RFC6749) separated by a semicolon "{{client_id}}:{{client_secret}}" `base64 encoded`
2. code for putting in the request is the `authorization code` (this code i have already)
3. its the `oauth2 flow`, so get code, then with code get the authorization code to make the finale api requests.

From the website of the api here is an example request to get the final token:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: identityservice.nmbrs.com
Authorization: Basic {{basicAuthentication}} 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

grant_type=authorization_code
&code={{code}}
&redirect_uri={{redirect_uri}}
```

and this should be the response (an example from the site of the api)

```
{
  "access_token": {{access_token}},
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": {{refresh_token}},
  "scope": {{scopes}}
}
```

Well now i want to make the request in python:

```
url = "https://identityservice.nmbrs.com/connect/token"

    headers = {
        "grant_type=authorization_code"
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'client_id':"23232323",     //example
        'client_secret':'12344555', //example
        'code':'1223455',           //i have this code
        'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:8080/callback'
    
        }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url,  headers=headers)
    print(response)
```

i get an 403 error, i dont think my code is right. I should get the `access_token.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to connect to the same service as you. Here is the way I got it working:

#### Imports

```
import urllib.parse
import base64
import requests
```

#### Credentais

```
client_id = ""
clientSecret = ""
authorization_code = ""
```

#### Encoding

URL encode the client_id and clientSecret

```
client_id = urllib.parse.quote(client_id.encode('utf8'))
clientSecret = urllib.parse.quote(clientSecret.encode('utf8'))
```

Join them togather separated by a semicolon "{client_id}:{client_secret}"
and base64 encoded.

```
code_bytes = f"{client_id}:{clientSecret}".encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(code_bytes)
base64_code = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
```

#### setting up the request

You keep geting the 403 error becouse you didn't include a **User-Agent** header.

```
url = "https://identityservice.nmbrs.com/connect/token"

headers ={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Authorization': f"Basic {base64_code}"
}

data = {   
    "grant_type" : "authorization_code",
    'code': authorization_code , 
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri
}

response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Tx , this did the trick

Comment: I was able to use this code with https://api.toodledo.com/ too. Thanks!   :-)